# Setting an identity column based on a field changed value

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, identity

I have a table where I used an `identity` as primary key (t_head_id), now this key became very long the way that upsets the client, so we changed it to a normal column select max + 1 and added new identity column (`id`) and another one computed (`id_per_year`) as id_per_year=id+'-' year(opeartion_date)

The prob now that I want to reset id not at the beginning of a year but when the client starts inserting new values of `operation_date`, since a new year can be started but the client is still inserting records of the passed year

How can I reset the identity based on the changing value of operation_date?

Comment: you can check the current year and add with those

Comment: This is not the work of an identity column

Comment: ***Please don't do this!*** The `SELECT MAX()+1` approach is ***utterly insecure!*** In a system with even just a little bit of concurrent usage, you **will** get duplicates! ***Don't do this!*** This is going to cause you massive pains and headaches in the future....... use the `IDENTITY`  - that's the ***only viable way*** to handle concurrency and getting safe "ID" numbers

Comment: I changed my post, I guess now it is clear

Answer (score 0):

You define a column of type `INT` (or `SMALLINT, TINYINT, BIGINT`) with the `IDENTITY` attribute:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ......
```

With this setup, SQL Server will automatically generate consecutive ID's for your table when rows are being inserted into your table.

With a type `INT`, starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases. With `BIGINT`, you get roughly **922 quadrillion** (922 with 15 zeros - 9'220'000 billions) - enough for you??

If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert a row every second, you need 66.5 **years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert one thousand rows every second, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Read more about it (with all the options there are) in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

So do you ***really*** need to change your `ID` column?? If you're getting close to hitting the `INT` limit (which I strongly doubt....), then change to a `BIGINT IDENTITY` - don't start using stuff like `SELECT MAX() + 1` which is inherently unsafe and **will eventually break** under load and produce duplicate values - safe yourself that grief, stick with `IDENTITY`!

Doesn't **292 million years** sound like **enough** for you???

Comment: The poster isn't particularly clear what they are trying to do, but I'd speculate that actually they are after some sort of sequence number within the year. id_per_year = 1-2015 effectively tells you that this is the first transaction within 2015.

Comment: Dear, Unfortunately yes am still need my changes, I just need the suitable method